# База данных vs обычные файлы

Tags: база-данных, файлы, веб-сервер

Есть следующая задача: на сайте добавить историю изменений личной информации юзеров.
К примеру, есть пользователь с username Вася. Каждый раз, когда он обновляет своё имя - необходимо сохранять информацию в историю.

**1 вариант**: каждый раз в mysql вносится строка с id данного пользователя, его новым именем и датой обновления.

**2 вариант**: сохранять каждое обновление в отдельный файл, который в свою очередь будет храниться в директории, название которой = id пользователя.

Может кто знает, какой вариант лучше выбрать?

Comment: Таблица "логи" в базе данных, как бы если SQL можно вообще без модификации кода сделать, на триггере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на сервере уже есть СУБД и приложение уже использует его каким-либо образом, то стоит использовать готовую инфраструктуру и сохранить единообразие доступа к данным.

Если нет, то 3-й вариант: Единый бинарный лог для всех пользователей формата "номер изменённой записи, номер изменённого поля, длинна нового значения, новое значение".

Comment: так а если количество пользователей будет исчисляться тысячами, разве единый лог не разрастется до безумных размеров?

Comment: скажите, если я захочу вывести историю изменений конкретного юзера. Есть ли вообще различие в скорости между чтением обычных файлов и СУБД ?

Comment: *Есть ли вообще различие в скорости между чтением обычных файлов и СУБД ?* Файл читать конечно, быстрее... Вот только обычный файл надо не только прочитать, но ещё отсортировать/отфильтровать. А с учётом этих операций - чтение файлов идёт плакать в уголок.

Comment: Добавлю к комментарию @Akina ещё то, что СУБД кэшируют горячие данные в памяти, так что даже обычное чтение может быть быстрее в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Плюс не забыть о синхронизации доступа к файлу(ам) из разных потоков

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov можете уточнить, что значит из "разных потоков"?

Comment: @Anenirycone в вашем приложении может быть больше одного [потока выполнения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Без синхронизации они просто испортят файл журнала.

Comment: @Anenirycone Когда у вас пользователь откроет две вкладки браузера и начнет одновременно редактировать информацию, то вы, если не предусмотрите монопольного доступа для записи, гарантировано испортите свои файлы